# boost::bimap not taking vector_of

Tags: c++, boost, bimap

```
typedef boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::vector_of<int>, boost::bimaps::vector_of<float> > bimap_t;
bimap_t mp;
mp.left.insert(bimap_t::left_value_type(2, 2.0f));
```

Why doesn't this work ? and gives compiler error on `insert()` It cannot find any `insert()` that takes `bimap_t::left_value_type` as argument.

However `boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::set_of<int>, boost::bimaps::vector_of<float> >` works. looks like the left cannot be vector. but as its bi directional it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Boost.Bimap before, but looking through the documentation it seems like the types of the `left` and `right` views, and accordingly the member functions you can use, depend on the collections you use as template parameters. You can see [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/reference/vector_of_reference.html) the methods you can use with a vector_of view. You could use:

```
mp.left.insert(mp.left.end(), bimap_t::left_value_type(2,2.0f));
mp.left.push_back(bimap_t::left_value_type(2,2.0f));
```

You could also use:

```
mp.left.push_front(bimap_t::left_value_type(2,2.0f));
```

but it is not recommended for performance reasons.

PS: If you use `bimap<boost::bimaps::set_of<int>, boost::bimaps::vector_of<float> >` your `insert` will work with the left view but it will fail with the right one.

Comment: Hmm then what is the generic way of insertion ? if its `set_of` I'll have to use `insert` but if its `vector_of` I need to `push_back` or pass end(). and to make this generic I'll need compile type checks like `enable_if` that will be too complex

Comment: `insert(Iterator, ValueType)` works with all the views that can insert. But if you use `map.end()` with a `set_of` view you will get worse performance that if you had used an iterator that preceded the point of insertion (O(log(N)) vs O(1)). I believe this is the reason why it is not as generic as you want, you are supposed to choose a bimap combination that suits your performance requirements and then use the methods allowed in that combination.

Comment: I have changed the comment in the beginning of the question, it know reflects my level of knowledge of the library more accurately. You should probably wait for a more reliable answer.